debug.getlocal: reading internal local variables
While playing around with debug.getlocal and debug.setlocal in Lua, i came across these constant values loaded at default. I've figured that the first is number of arguments passed into the file, the second is the userdata and the third seems to be some kinda of C function, which has a constant memory address of 004016f0, calling it does nothing. The last is a bit weird, when there are no local variables defined before it returns a constant function at memory: 6c09e0d0, this function cant be saved into a variable which is also quite weird.
Can someone please explain this behavior? and what the functions may be?
code:
print(debug.getlocal(2, 1)) -- ARGS
print(debug.getlocal(2, 2)) -- USERDATA
print(debug.getlocal(2, 3)) -- CONSTANT C FUNC?
print(debug.getlocal(1, 1)) -- CONSTANT FUNC, IF NO LOCAL VARS

local k, v = debug.getlocal(1, 1) -- NIL, NIL?

local k2, v2 = debug.getlocal(2, 3)
for key, value in pairs(debug.getinfo(v2)) do
    print(key, value)
end

output:
(C temporary)   2
(C temporary)   userdata: 00802290
(C temporary)   function: 004016f0
(temporary)     function: 6c09e0d0
lastlinedefined -1
func    function: 004016f0
ftransfer       0
istailcall      false
ntransfer       0
namewhat
currentline     -1
source  =[C]
isvararg        true
short_src       [C]
nparams 0
what    C
nups    0
linedefined     -1

